# Why is my XWebView served index.html using the file scheme and how do I change it?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, gcdwebserver

I'm using a `WKWebView` to serve the `index.html` of a single page web app ([ember](http://emberjs.com)) like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let webview = WKWebView(
            frame: view.frame, 
            configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration()
        )
        view.addSubview(webview)

        let root = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL!
        let url = root.URLByAppendingPathComponent("dist/index.html")
        webview.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessToURL: root)
```

Which works just fine to load the index file. But the index file is requesting it's links and resources using the file scheme? If I inspect the app with Safari as it runs in the inspector I see this error for all local resources:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: ... file:///dist/assets/css/vendor.css
```

Which in the `index.html` looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/assets/vendor.css">
```

What I want is for resource requests to go to my [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer) that I set up like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var webServer: GCDWebServer?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        self.webServer = GCDWebServer()
        self.webServer!.addGETHandlerForBasePath("/",
            directoryPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath,            
            indexFilename: nil,
            cacheAge: 3600,
            allowRangeRequests: true
        )
        self.webServer!.startWithPort(8080, bonjourName: "GCD Web Server")
        print("GCD Server running at: \(self.webServer!.serverURL)")
        return true
```

And I have added the `dist` folder to the bundle in Xcode.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm the author of XWebView. I'm not quite understand your requirement. If you use XWebView for file URL support on iOS 8, why include  the GCDWebServer? Any bug reports or questions, you can file an issue ticket on github, so we can try best to support you.

Comment: thnx for looking at this, the issue here is not with XWebView - but rather my misuse of loadFileURL instead of loadRequest. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how HTML works. HREFs that aren't absolute are relative to wherever the referencing page came from. So if you have `images/foo.png` on `file:///dir/index.html`, the browser will request `file:///dir/images/foo.png`.

If you need the browser to fetch the resources from a different location, you'll need to use absolute URLs in your HTML (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/whatever`).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. I just needed to serve my `index.html` from localhost by using `webview.loadRequest` instead of `webview.loadFileURL` like this:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let serverURL = appDelegate.webServer!.serverURL
let indexURL = serverURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("dist/index.html")
webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: indexURL))
```

As Andrew Medico pointed out, `href`'s are relative to their parent page, so if I serve `index.html` from localhost, then all my resources are requested from localhost as well. Solved.